# Disable automatic alt text in Word for Mac

Tags: ms-office, accessibility

When I paste an image into a Word for Mac document, it automatically adds alt text. How can I disable this "feature"? All the sources I can find online only explain how to do it on Word for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it is at Preferences > General > Automatic Alt Text (Word 16.30 at the moment)

Comment: Also true for PowerPoint 16.50

Answer (score 0):

Toggle Automatic Alt Text on and off

If you don't want automatically generated alt text to be added to inserted pictures, you can turn off the automatic alt text option in PowerPoint and Word. If you change your mind later, you can just as easily turn it back on.

Press Command+, (Comma). The preferences window opens.

Select General.

In the Automatic Alt Text section, select or unselect the Automatically generate alt text for me option.

Comment: This does not seem to be there in MacOs ventura.