# Disable automatic alt text in Word for MacOS Ventura

Tags: macos, ventura

Disable automatic alt text in Word for MacOS Ventura.

I want to use Option + keys for some other purpose. The current combination prints some strange alphabets.

[Disable automatic alt text in Word for Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381566/disable-automatic-alt-text-in-word-for-mac)
I can't seem to the find section as per the answers in above. It looks it has been moved to someplace else.

Comment: You're looking to disable it ONLY in Word?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve, what you do, and what happens? Do you mean characters like åß∂ƒ©∆˚¬πø^¨¥†®´∑ when you hold down Option and press keys? ("strange alphabet") Or do you mean the addition of alternative text as metadata for an image, which is what the linked question refers to?

Comment: yes characters like åß∂ƒ©∆˚¬πø^¨¥†®´∑ are appearing. I want to use Option + keys in browser with a greasemonkey script. But, this alphabet gets typed instead of greasemonkey script getting executed.